# ivprobit error: the leading minor of order # is not positive definite

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run a ivprobit regression on individual crime and demographic variables. The dependent variable is annualassault and I have 24 independent variables regarding to the demographic. The r.h.s endogenous variable is sogs_total, and the instruments are drivetime and distance. I got the error:  the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite.

I reduced my independent variables to only 5 because I think I might be over fitting the model (too many variables), but I still get the same error.

```
library(ivprobit)

ivprobit.assault = ivprobit(annualassault ~ age +sex+ education_1+ education_2+ 
education_3+ education_4+ education_5+ education_6+ education_7                        
+maritalstatus_0+maritalstatus_1+maritalstatus_2+maritalstatus_3+maritalstatus_4+
a_nondm+d_nonam+m_nonad+ ad_nonm+am_nond
+dm_nona+ adm |sogs_total|drivetime + distance, newdata)

ivprobit.assault2 = ivprobit(annualassault ~ age +sex+ education_1+maritalstatus_1+
am_nond|sogs_total|drivetime + distance, newdata)
```

Error in chol.default(mat) : 
  the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite